# system call giving not enough memory in c++

Tags: c, system-calls

I was trying to enter list of files in a file by using command

> system("dir *.txt /b :gen> file.txt");

in a c program

this is giving me a error saying "not enough memory"

but when i am writing the same code (dir *.txt /b :gen >file.txt) in cmd it is working fine

and also i tried some other codes also like "cd"  they are also giving same error

error is being displayed if i use perror("error");

Comment: can you please post the exact error message that you get?

Comment: mycode:   #include<process.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
//#include<unistd.h>
void main()
{
system("dir e:\*.java /b /o /p :gen >file.txt";
perror("error:");
}                                                                           output: error: Not enough memory

Answer (score 1):

You can't rely on `perror()` to correctly report status from a process started using `system()`.

All that `perror()` does is inspect the value of `errno`, but that's not set by `system()`.

See the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) on how to actually catch status information from `system()`.

Comment: if i am not using perror it is not giving any knid of error . then also code is not working